# Access 2007/2010 Source Control

Tags: ms-access, version-control, tfs

I'm using the Access Developer Extensions to attempt to source control this access database in TFS, however, I'm not sure I am doing it right. I can add a .mdb to source control and create a database from that source control.

I'm probably making a stupid mistake, but I can't figure out how to close the database I created from source control and reopen it while it's still under source.

Does anyone know of any tips or guides on this? I've searched for help on Access Developer Extentsions but I haven't found much. Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: What have you already tried, and what happens when you try to reopen it?  You can't open it at all, or you open it and the source code control is disabled?

Comment: One thing you can't do is to move the database after you've created it.  Well, you can move it, but you can only use source code control if you move it back to the path where it was created.

Comment: I've been informed that you can't track changes to the individual objects. Is that true? If so, then why do I see all the objects in the .mdb separated out in TFS?

Comment: You can't track changes to individual tables, relationships, and similar ("data and misc objects").  Forms, reports, queries, yes: you can track changes to these individual objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found what I was doing wrong. My database automatically compacts on close, so when it tried to do this Access asked me if I wanted "to remove the compacted database from source control". I thought this meant it would just not store the .mdb file, but still keep the objects (like tables, vba, queries, forms, etc) under source. However, this appears to completely remove it... from MSDN:

"Changes to Microsoft Access Behavior

Using the Compact Database Command

In order to take a database that is under source code control and deliver it to a user, you need a way to cut the database's ties to source code control. When you compact a database that is under source code control, Microsoft Access 2000 prompts you to remove the database from source code control.

To remove the database from source code control, Microsoft Access simply removes the Visual SourceSafe properties from the Microsoft Access database and its objects."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155494(v=office.10).aspx

When I said do not remove compacted database from source control, my database and it's objects stayed under source.